# Run Tomcat within Eclipse as a different user in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, tomcat

I would like to run eclipse using my user, and tomcat inside eclipse using the user "tomcat"
Is that possible? Any ideas?
It is not a problem that is a security issue, as I am in my home behing a firewall, with no services opened to the world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Eclipse runs Tomcat, but it will need for sure to run an executable. So, you can `chown` that executable to the user `tomcat` and then `setuid` the executable. For example:

```
chown tomcat:tomcat /path/to/bin/tomcat
chmod +s /path/to/bin/tomcat
```

With the setuid bit any executable is ran as the user who owns it.

I didn't test it, but it should work fine.